# SharePoint Modern Site PnP provisioning issues with Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

SharePoint Online (Microsoft 365)
PnP.PowerShell - 1.10.0

I am using the following PowerShell commands to save a modern site as a template:

```
    $url = "https://<private>.sharepoint.com/sites/StudiesBillingCenter"
    
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Interactive
    
    Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out "D:\Office365_Sites_Templates_Export_Import\StudiesBillingCenter\StudiesBillingCenter-site-template.xml"

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

And the following code to import it to another tenant SharePoint Online site:

```
$url = "https://<private-1>.sharepoint.com/sites/Studies-Billing"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Interactive
 
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Verbose -Debug -Path "D:\Office365_Sites_Templates_Export_Import\StudiesBillingCenter\StudiesBillingCenter-site-template.xml"

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

And I am getting a lot of error messages during the template import, like this one:

```
Column 'Report_x0020_Description' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate], ServerException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.InvokeSiteTemplate
```

As a result Lists were actually created but views were not imported at all.

But when I was using handlers (for lists) and imported them one by one there were no error messages and all views were created:

```
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Handlers Lists -ListsToExtract "GL-2022 - List" "D:\Office365_Sites_Templates_Export_Import\StudiesBillingCenter\StudiesBillingCenter-site-template-List-2022.xml"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

I have deleted the whole `<pnp:ListInstance   ... Reports%20List ...  </pnp:ListInstance>` in xml file and  the script ran with no error messages. "Content and Structure Reports" list caused my problems (see my comments).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the columns "Report_x0020_Description" is in the site columns list of the destination site.  It may be that this is column was defined in your content type hub and not published to the destination site.

Comment: My destination site is a Team site and it has not been customized in any way before the PnP provisioning. So, of course, it didn't have any elements that were imported from the source site. When I imported a list-only template there were no errors besides "Cannot find principle" which is an expected error message. And this is not the only thing that PnP complained of (like,  ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x01002CF74A4DAE39480396EEA7A4BA2BE5FB", which is Reusable HTML, which is a built-in Content Type)

Comment: Can you verify that the field was exported in the .xml file (a simple search should suffice).  If should be in a FieldRef Tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Yes, it is there but it looks like it is listed in the view of  non-existent List. Url="{site}/Reports List/AllItems.aspx" Probably this list has been deleted. But how can I find that view on the source site to delete it. I can't comment it out in the template xml file.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Yes, it is there but it looks like it is listed in the view of  non-existent List. Url="{site}/Reports List/AllItems.aspx" Probably this list has been deleted. But how can I find that view on the source site to delete it. I can't comment it out in the template xml file. I guess, I found it: Reports%20List "Content and Structure Reports".  SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure was probably activated initially but now it is not. So this is the problem now?